# Authentication + Keeping Session user ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a project with ASP.NET MVC4, and I have to login and to keep the current user information like the id, his name,etc to use them in the other pages

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Auth(string login, string password)
    {
        // Customer c = null;
        Customer cus = (from e in db.Customers where e.Login == login && e.Password == password select e).SingleOrDefault();
        if (cus != null)
        {


            //String s = User.Identity.Name;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
```

I guess I just need the Session Code, so please anyone can help me ??

Comment: You could have a look at how it's been done by the generated code in the Account controller that came with empty project. It uses `FormsAuthentication` class

Answer (score 0):

in MVC4 you can use knockoutjs and breeze using that you can pass value from one view to another in the form of context and can retrieve that value on view activation.

please view this [link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller) for breeze

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
    Customer cus = (from e in db.Customers where e.Login == login && e.Password == password select e).SingleOrDefault();
    if (cus != null)
    {
        // the boolean is for creating a persistent cookie
        // also after this point User.Identity.Name should be == login
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, true);

        // store more info in session and access it in other places
        Session["Customer"] = cus;

        //String s = User.Identity.Name;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

That said, it's not a good idea to store sensitive user information in the `Session` last time I checked ASP.NET Session Hijacking was still a thing. Store only what you need. Hope this helps.